# VueJS: Method is not defined on the instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, components

I made a component for a drag and drop element. What I want to do is use my .vue template file, instead of writing all the HTML on the single line after the template. (When I do write it in the component itself, it works fine, but just doesn't look good.) I need it to be a component because it can be that there is more than one component on one page.

Here is my .js file:

```
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import SingleFileUpload from './single-file-upload.vue'

    Vue.component ('test', SingleFileUpload, {
        delimiters: ['${', '}'], // Avoid Twig conflicts
        data() {
            return filelist // Store our uploaded files
        },
        methods: {
          onChange() {
            this.filelist = [...this.$refs.file.files];
          },
          remove(i) {
            this.filelist = [];
          },
          dragover(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            // Add some visual fluff to show the user can drop its files
            if (!event.currentTarget.classList.contains('highlight')) {
              event.currentTarget.classList.remove('bg-haze');
              event.currentTarget.classList.add('highlight');
            }
          },
          dragleave(event) {
            // Clean up
            event.currentTarget.classList.add('bg-haze');
            event.currentTarget.classList.remove('highlight');
          },
          drop(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.$refs.file.files = event.dataTransfer.files;
            this.onChange(); // Trigger the onChange event manually
            // Clean up
            event.currentTarget.classList.add('bg-haze');
            event.currentTarget.classList.remove('highlight');
          }
        },
        template: SingleFileUpload
    })

    new Vue({ 
        el: '#App',
       })
```

This is my .vue file

```
<template>
    <div class="file-upload__wrapper">
        <div
            class="file-upload__drop-area"
            @dragover="dragover"
            @dragleave="dragleave"
            @drop="drop"
        >
            <input
                type="file"
                name="file-upload-bank"
                id="file-upload-bank"
                class="d-none"
                @change="onChange"
                ref="file"
                accept=".pdf,.jpg,.jpeg,.png"
            />
            <ul v-if="this.filelist.length" v-cloak>
                <li v-for="file in filelist" v-bind:key="file.id">
                    <span>Bestand: ${ file.name }</span
                    ><button
                        type="button"
                        @click="remove(filelist.indexOf(file))"
                        title="Verwijder bestand"
                    >
                        <i class="icon-cross"></i>
                    </button>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <label for="file-upload-bank" class="block cursor-pointer" v-else>
                <div>Kies een bestand of drag and drop het bestand</div>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

In my page I use  to place it.

Unfortunately, I get this error (which I get for all methods I use in the template).

```
vue.common.dev.js:630 [Vue warn]: Property or method "dragover" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

---> <Test> at assets/scripts/vue-components/forms/single-file-upload.vue
       <Root>
```

Who knows what I do wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that it is the correct way of defining components? https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-component

Comment: Vue.component( id, [definition] )